# View contents of data.mdb file of LMDB

Tags: c++, database, lmdb, nosql

I have built the `lmdb(symas lightning memory mapped database)` in my `Ubuntu 14.04`. I could successfully write a program in `C++` using `lmdb` and add data to it. Now I have a  `data.mdb` and `lock.mdb` file in my folder. I tried opening `data.mdb` using `MDB Viewer`, but it shows nothing. Is there some `GUI` that I could use to view the database file. Also is it possible to add more than one value associated with a key(like student name, address, phone number associated with id)?

Comment: What is "MDB Viewer"? It doesn't sound like anything the LMDB project provides. The tools provided with LMDB are command-line tools such as `mdb_stat` and `mdb_dump`. Read their instructions to dump out your database.

Comment: ok..MDB Viewer was a tool available in Ubuntu software repository to open and view .mdb files.It is not relaated to LMDB project. I ll try with the command line tools you mentioned ..

Comment: Looks like MDB Viewer is meant for Microsoft Access files. It is indeed unrelated to LMDB and it will not be able to open LMDB files, despite the coincidence of file extensions.

Comment: @ArtoBendiken: but `mdb_stat` gives the status and `mdb_copy` backups the database. It has nothing to do with the contents, I think.. So no way to view the key-value pair?

Comment: Those are two of the other tools bundled with LMDB, but note my suggest for `mdb_dump`, specifically. That tool lets you view the contents of the database file.

Comment: @ArtoBendiken: mdb_dump gives the data.. But everything as numbers(i hope memory addresses). Can you please help me by telling if there is something like collections of MongoDB in LMDB?

Comment: There is a command-line option, probably `-p`, for getting ASCII output. And yes, LMDB supports duplicate keys, which enables you to store multiple values per key.